# minimize/solve a system of equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Im attempting to minimize $f(x,y,z)=xyz \: wrt, h_1(x,y,z)=x+y+z-45=0,\: h_2(x,y,z)= 2x-y=0$

I have $\bigtriangledown f(x,y,z)= \lambda_1h_1(x,y,z) + \lambda_2h_2(x,y,z) $

Im down to

$yz= \lambda_1 +2\lambda_2 \\xy = \lambda_1 - \lambda_2 \\xy = \lambda_1
\\x+y+z = 45\\y=2x$

Im having trouble simplifying this,
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: is it in the form minimize $f(x,y,z)$ subject to $h_1(x,y,z)=0$ and $h_2(x,y,z)=0$

Comment: @dineshdileep yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the optimization problem

$$\displaystyle \begin{align}
 \underset{x,y,z}{\text{minimize}} \quad & f(x,y,z) = xyz
 \\
 \\ \text{subject to} \quad & h_1(x,y,z) = x+y+z - 45 = 0
 \\ & h_2(x,y,z) = 2x - y = 0
\end{align}$$

The method of Lagrangian Multipliers gives the following system of equations

$$\displaystyle \begin{align}
 \nabla f(x, y, z) - \sum_{k = 1}^{M} \lambda_k \nabla h_k(x,y,z) & = 0 \\
 \nabla f(x, y, z) & = \lambda_1 \nabla h_1(x,y,z) + \lambda_2 \nabla h_1(x,y,z) \\
 \begin{pmatrix} yz \\ xz \\ xy \end{pmatrix} & = \lambda_1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + \lambda_2 \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$

Or more simply, (1) $yz = \lambda_1 + 2 \lambda_2$, (2) $xz = \lambda_1 - \lambda_2$, (3) $xy = \lambda_1$, (4) $2x = y$, and (5) $x + y + z = 45$. Substituting (4) into (1, 3, 5) produces (1') $2xz = \lambda_1 + 2 \lambda_2$, (3') $2x^2 = \lambda_1$, and (5') $3x + z = 45$.

Thus, $x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \sqrt{\lambda_1}$, $y = \pm \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\lambda_1}$ and $z = 45 \mp 3 \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \sqrt{\lambda_1}$. Therefore, the minimum takes place when $\lambda_1 = 0$, yielding $(x, y, z) = (0, 0, 45)$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that we need Lagrange multipliers. From equation $h_2$ it follows that $y=2x$. This together with equation $h_1$ gives $z=45-x-y=45-x-2x=45-3x$. Therefore $f(x,y,z)$ can be rewritten as $$f(x,y,z) = xyz = x2x(45-3x)=2x^2(45-3x)=-6x^3+90x^2=f(x)$$
Now $f'(x)=-18x^2+180x$ and from that it follows that $x=0$ and $x=10$ are potential extrema. With $f''(x)$ we can see that $x=0$ is a minima. Therefore $y=0$ and $z=45$. Note that this is only a local minima.